Can't Correct URI on Android for Upload to Firebase Storage
i have attempted MANY solutions for this but I still cannot solve the file path on Android. IOS works perfectly.
Android Logs
LOG  Initiating photo upload for photo index: 1
LOG  Original selected image URI: file:///data/user/0/com.project/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_8848657f-1626-4c1a-92fd-afcf40385775.jpg
LOG  Resolved upload URI for Firebase: /data/user/0/com.project/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_8848657f-1626-4c1a-92fd-afcf40385775.jpg
ERROR  Error in photo upload or Firestore update: [Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'RNFBStorageModule': java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The storage Uri cannot contain a path element.]
IOS Logs
LOG  Initiating photo upload for photo index: 2
LOG  Original selected image URI: file:///Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/79FD1F01-AAAE-4231-A799-679957189DEB/data/Containers/Data/Application/5510B661-3B18-4169-8816-DC85554BDCA9/tmp/A1E292BC-3C77-4345-AD48-6657F431F1D9.jpg
LOG  Resolved upload URI for Firebase: file:///Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/79FD1F01-AAAE-4231-A799-679957189DEB/data/Containers/Data/Application/5510B661-3B18-4169-8816-DC85554BDCA9/tmp/A1E292BC-3C77-4345-AD48-6657F431F1D9.jpg
LOG  Firebase storage reference created for: profile_pictures/ocuMUzD4XoXtXjpQXsUmg_2.jpg
LOG  File upload successful.

import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { stat } from '@dr.pogodin/react-native-fs';
import { launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

// Helper function to convert file URI to content URI on Android
const getPathForFirebaseStorage = async (uri) => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') return uri; // For iOS, we use the URI directly.

  // For Android, we need to resolve the file path using the stat method
  const statResult = await stat(uri);
  return statResult.path;
};

const uploadPhoto = async (photoIndex) => {
  const user = auth().currentUser;
  if (user) {
    setUploading(true);

    const options = {
      mediaType: 'photo',
      maxWidth: 300,
      maxHeight: 400,
      includeBase64: false,
    };

    try {
      console.log('Initiating photo upload for photo index:', photoIndex);

      const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
          if (response.didCancel) {
            reject('User cancelled image picker');
          } else if (response.errorCode) {
            reject('ImagePicker Error: ' + response.errorMessage);
          } else {
            resolve(response);
          }
        });
      });

      if (response.assets && response.assets.length > 0) {
        let uploadUri = response.assets[0].uri;
        console.log('Original selected image URI:', uploadUri);

        // Get correct path for Firebase Storage
        const fileUri = await getPathForFirebaseStorage(uploadUri);
        console.log('Resolved upload URI for Firebase:', fileUri);

        const fileName = `profile_pictures/${user.uid}_${photoIndex}.jpg`;
        const storageRef = storage().refFromURL(`${FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET}/profile_pictures/${user.uid}_${photoIndex}.jpg`);

        console.log('Firebase storage reference created for:', fileName);

        // Upload the file to Firebase storage using the resolved file path
        await storageRef.putFile(fileUri);
        console.log('File upload successful.');

        // Retrieve the download URL after upload
        const downloadUrl = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
        console.log('Download URL retrieved:', downloadUrl);

        // Update the state with the new photo URL
        updatePhotoUrlState(photoIndex, downloadUrl);
        await UserService.createUserProfile(user.uid, { [`profilePicture${photoIndex}`]: downloadUrl });
        console.log('Firestore updated successfully with new photo URL.');

        MixpanelManager.track('Profile Photo Added', { photoIndex: photoIndex });
        AnalyticsService.logEvent('photo_uploaded', { userId: user.uid, photoIndex: photoIndex });

        setPhotoUploaded(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in photo upload or Firestore update:', error);
      Alert.alert('Photo upload failed', error.message || error);
    } finally {
      setUploading(false);
    }
  }
};


import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

// Adjusted to upload files directly from the device's storage
const uploadProfilePicture = async (userId, filePath) => {
  try {
    console.log('Starting upload for user:', userId);
    const storageRef = storage().ref(`profile_pictures/${userId}.jpg`);
    const uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(filePath); // Using putFile instead of put

    // Monitor upload progress, success, and errors
    uploadTask.on(
      'state_changed',
      (snapshot) => {
        // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
        const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log(`Upload is ${progress}% done`);
      },
      (error) => {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        console.error('Upload error:', error);
      },
      async () => {
        // Handle successful uploads on complete
        const downloadURL = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        return downloadURL;
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Upload profile picture error:', error);
    throw error; // Rethrow the error to be handled by the caller
  }
};

export default {
  uploadProfilePicture,
};


I have also attempted (with fail)

modified the code to ensure that the file:// prefix was added for Android using:

if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !resolvedURI.startsWith('file://')) {
resolvedURI = file://${resolvedURI};
}

converted the image to a base64 string and uploading it as a data URL using:

const base64String = await RNFS.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64');
const blob = data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64String};
await storageRef.putString(blob, 'data_url');

modified the Firebase storage reference creation from storage().refFromURL() to storage().ref() to avoid issues with the URL.

using Firebase’s putFile method directly without base64 conversion
if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !uploadUri.startsWith('file://')) {
uploadUri = file://${uploadUri};
}
await storageRef.putFile(uploadUri);


